# How to mounting a Windows shared folder with samba?

Tags: windows, mount, samba, shared-folders

I'm following a lot of tutorials but nothings work with me.

So my question is what I need to have samba services to mount and windows shared folder?

My last trying is this:

```
kevin@AnayaNet:~$ smbtree
Enter kevin's password: 
CIBERBYTE
    \\PC01                  
        \\PC01\Documentos c     
        \\PC01\Nueva carpeta    
        \\PC01\C                
        \\PC01\IPC$             IPC remota
```

Then I run this command:

```
kevin@AnayaNet:~$ sudo mount -t smbfs -o user=administrador,password=Bug.$%10 //PC01/Documentos Desktop/Shared_PC01/
```

And what I got was this:

```
mount error: could not resolve address for PC01: Unknown error
```

Thanks in advanced Linux people.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the ip address resolution failed.

you need change PC01 to the ip address of machine on which the samba server runs.

if you want a gui client for samba, you can try nautilus (the default file manager for ubuntu). nautilus supports a variety of remote services, e.g. smb, afp, sftp, ssh, davs, dav, ftp.

open "Connect to Server" dialog from nautilus menu. and type the server address,
e.g. smb://10.0.0.6 (or smb://shared,if you have set up your hosts file or dns server)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying out cifs-utils if you're having trouble  mounting a Windows Shared Folder/Drive

```
sudo apt-get install cifs-utils
```

Then, get to know your host computer's IP adress. Do this on the host PC's terminal.

Windows:

```
ipconfig
```

Linux:

```
ifconfig [ADAPTER, Eg. eth0]
```

Then, create a folder where you want to mount it. In this example, I'm mounting in my Home. My username is Anna, but yours will be different.

```
cd /home/Anna
mkdir Windows-Share
```

Then, mount the samba share to the folder.`

```
mount.cifs //IPADRESS/FOLDERNAME /home/Anna/Windows-Share -o username= USERNAME YOU SET FOR YOUR SHARE
```

Correct me if I'm on the wrong path/topic.

Sincerely,
Anna

I'm a newbie to helping people.